# 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory with type UserController is not registered inside GetIt. (But it is)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

I have a two apps project, I am using get_it to get the profile picture from firebase Storage
.
The problem is that in the first app the code is working perfectly and the sign in procedure finish up normally, but in this one I copied the code as it was and made the necessary changes (imports mostly) however getting the profile picture using get_it is interrupting the signing and the sign up procedure and returning this error in the console:

```
/flutter ( 4798): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory with  type UserController is not registered inside GetIt.
package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:372
E/flutter ( 4798): (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
E/flutter ( 4798): Did you forget to register it?)
E/flutter ( 4798): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 4798): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 4798): #2      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType
package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:372
E/flutter ( 4798): #3      _GetItImplementation.get
package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:393
E/flutter ( 4798): #4      _SignInPageState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:nhafeflek/…/authentication/sign_in.dart:193
E/flutter ( 4798): #5      _SignInPageState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:nhafeflek/…/authentication/sign_in.dart:190
E/flutter ( 4798): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap
E/flutter ( 4798): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:198
E/flutter ( 4798): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:613
E/flutter ( 4798): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:298
E/flutter ( 4798): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:232
E/flutter ( 4798): #11     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:563
E/flutter ( 4798): #12     PointerRouter._dispatch
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94
E/flutter ( 4798): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139
E/flutter ( 4798): #14     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:614:13)
E/flutter ( 4798): #15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137
E/flutter ( 4798): #16     PointerRouter.route
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123
E/flutter ( 4798): #17     GestureBinding.handleEvent
E/flutter ( 4798): #18     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:425
E/flutter ( 4798): #19     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:326
E/flutter ( 4798): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:380
E/flutter ( 4798): #21     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:344
E/flutter ( 4798): #22     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:302
E/flutter ( 4798): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:285
E/flutter ( 4798): #24     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1442:13)
E/flutter ( 4798): #25     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 4798): #26     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter ( 4798): #27     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
E/flutter ( 4798): #28     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
E/flutter ( 4798): #29     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
```

and as I already said it is registered and already working in the other app and here is my code:

My locator.dart file

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/services/storage.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/services/userController.dart';

var locator = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> setupServices() async {
  locator.registerSingleton<AuthService>(AuthService());
  locator.registerSingleton<StorageService>(StorageService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton<UserController>(() => UserController());
}
```

My UserController.dart file:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/models/user.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/services/locator.dart';
import 'package:nhafeflek/services/storage.dart';

class UserController {
  late Userr _currentUser;
  final AuthService _authService = locator.get<AuthService>();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late Future init;
  final StorageService _storageService = locator.get<StorageService>();

  UserController() {
    init = initUser();
  }

  Future<Userr> initUser() async {
    _currentUser = await _authService.getUser();
    return _currentUser;
  }

  Userr get currentUser => _currentUser;

  Future<void> uploadProfilePicture(File image) async {
    _currentUser.avatarUrl = await _storageService.uploadFile(image);
  }

  Userr? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return Userr(uid: user.uid);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<String> getDownloadUrl() async {
    return await _storageService
        .getUserProfileImageDownloadUrl(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
  }

  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    _currentUser =
        await _authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    _currentUser = Userr(
      uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
      avatarUrl: await getDownloadUrl());
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User barber = result.user!;

      return _userFromFirebaseUser(barber);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

My SignIn button:

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () async {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
         dynamic result = await locator
          .get<UserController>()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          if (result == null) {
             setState(() =>
                error = 'Something went wrong... Please try again!');
             }
          }
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
         shadowColor:
             MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color(0xff5680a7)),
         backgroundColor:
             MaterialStateProperty.all(const Color(0xff5680a7)),
         padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 120, vertical: 15)),
         shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
             side: const BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xff5680a7), width: 3)))),
   child: const Text(
      'Sign In',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
   )
)
```

> If you need any other sample of the code don't hesitate for asking. I seek your help.